# Child div behind parent div, how to fix link?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a child `<div>` (with a link in it) behind its parent `<div>`, but the links doesn't work.

I am using `z-index: -1`, so maybe the link is being drawn "behind" the `<body>`.

Is there a way to achive this without breaking the link?

Thanks

---

The CSS

```
    .front {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #EA7600;
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }

    .back {
        width: 300px; height: 50px; background: #93CDFB;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

---

The HTML

```
<div class="front">

<div class="back">

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">This link works</a>

</div>

</div>


&nbsp;


<div class="front" style="z-index: 1">

<div class="back" style="z-index: -1">

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">This link doesn't work</a>

</div>

</div>
```

---

The Result

[alt text http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8137/screenshot20100723at105.png](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8137/screenshot20100723at105.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent half an hour reading the (very complex) [CSS specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers), but I'm a little bit confused about positioned elements and stacking contexts. However, after fiddling around, I found that

```
body {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

actually works! So does

```
body {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will turn the body element into a new stocking context, meaning that body (not html) will serve as a [canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html#stacking-defs) to the .back div.

Answer (score 0):

maybe for the front one: display:inline or float:left

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed.  If you check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkbb8/1/), you'll see it in action.

As you suspected, it was the -1 `z-index` causing you trouble.  By moving the teal container outside the orange one and giving a z-index to the orange container, you're able to maintain the stacking order and the link still works.

Comment: Thanks Pat but I am not able to change the fact that the teal box is a child of the orange box. Is there a way to do it without touching the Html?

Comment: Unfortunately no - as you've discovered, stacking a child under its parent is sketchy at best.  To be honest, I'd never even tried a negative z-index, so I was surprised at the result.

Answer (score -1):

How about giving the child link a larger z-index?

So for the CSS

```
.back a {
  z-index: 50
}
```

& leave the others as they currently are?